# Removing Google Chrome disables links from Outlook Email

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-outlook, internet-explorer, email

I had been using a beta version of Google Chrome.  I recently installed the IE 9 Beta and removed the Chrome from my computer.  Now, when I get an email with a hyper-link in outlook and try to open it, I get a message that the "operation has been cancelled due to restrictions on this computer.  see system administrator".

I have set the program access default to use IE as the default web browser but I still get this message.  What else should I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you run IE9 and set IE9 to be the default browser in the Tools --> Options area?

It's not just your outlook that needs to use IE as the default, your windows OS needs to know that IE9 is the default browser.

**UPDATE** this is usually a corrupt registry key... have you tried [this](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/link_restrict.htm) fix?

Usually it's this key:

```
HKEY_Local_Machine\Software\Classes\htmlfile\shell\open\command
```

Comment: Yes, I have done that

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to an article describing how to fix a corrupt registry key that usually causes this problem.